# hibernate createSQLQuery use CacheQuery?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

```
Query query=getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
                "select...

getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(true);
List result= query.list();
getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(false);

return result;
```

may i know when i do manual "createSQLQuery" how to use cacheQuery? the above doesnt cache the result. show_sql still showing every request get from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK when using `createSQLQuery`, you must use an explicit `.addScalar` or `.addEntity` if `setCacheable` is `true`, or hibernate gets confused on casting. Apart from that, my understanding is that it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure ApplicationContext

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate .cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
```

Comment: already added that. it work only for DetachedCriteria , but for manual sql like above will it work?